# Android localization: find only the strings that are used in the app

Tags: android, localization

We are working on an App that has some history, and strings have been added to and removed from it a lot in the past. It resulted in the presence of lots of unused strings in the strings.xml file. As we pay for the localization to new languages, translating the redundant strings costs us money.

Is there a way to get the list of all the string keys that are definitely used somewhere in the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Android Studio then do this,

Menu -> Analyze -> Run Inspection by Name -> Type "Unused resources"

Hope it helps..!

Do mark as an answer so that it would be useful to others...

Comment: It isn't exactly what I was asking, but i will mark it as an answer if I don't get the exact one. The thing is that this will give me the list of strings that are not used in the project, and i will have to subtract them from the list of all strings to get the ones that are used. But the app we are working on also has an ios build with some strings that are used only there. I want to get the list of strings used in Andr + in IOS and add them together.